# Make ArrayList available for other Classes/Activities after leaving AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm new to Android development and I have some trouble understanding how to handle plain old java objects / variables / containers in Android. They seem to be not longer available after finishing an AsyncTask or leaving an Activity.

For e.g.: Via AsyncTask I'm gettings some data, push it into an ArrayList from another class (works pretty fine - I can see the result on my mapview ;-)) and want to make it available for other classes/Activities.

How can I handle this / what is a good practice in Android for that matter?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can always use global variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I handle this / what is a good practice in Android for that
>   matter?

If you want to pass primitive types and objects through Activities you have a few options:

- An usage of [`putExtra()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra) methods of [`Intent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) - you can pass primitive datatypes and objects as well
- Wrap primitive datatypes and objects into [`Bundle`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) and pass to [`Intent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

But if you want to pass objects via Activities they have to implement [`Serializable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html) or [`Parcelable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) interface.

> They seem to be not longer available after finishing an AsyncTask or
>   leaving an Activity.

Yes. If you have variables, objects defined and initialised in Activity class they live as long as Activity lives. So if you want to persist some data you are once again a few options:

- You can persist primitive and reference types(int, double, String
  etc.) with [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) they work as key-value pairs.
- For storing objects you can create their "copy" in `SQLite` where
  objects are presented as tables where properties of object are equal
  to columns in database.
- If your objects implement [`Serializable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html) interface, you can serialize them into
  binary file and whenever you want deserialize them for an usage.

Comment: Thank's for that helpful and detailed explanation :-) I guess I will solve this via SQLite, which seems to be solution that implies extensibility in persistence matters.

Answer (score 0):

See here for ways to store data
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

This first answer shows an example of how to pass data between activities
[How do I pass data between Activities in Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android)